# Render label from Model based on language selected

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making a multi-lingual app using angular. I am showing a list of categories.
The api response is like this:

```
[
  {
    name_en: 'Watches',
    name_ar: 'راقب'
  },
  {
    name_en: 'Toys',
    name_ar: 'ألعاب الأطفال'
  }
]
```

I am looping on this array to show :

```
<label *ngFor='let item of items'>{{item.name_en}}</label>
```

On Arabic language select, I want to show `name_ar` in label instead of `name_en`. How can this be achieved ? I can also have more then two languages.

PS: I can always pass the language to server and retrieve the field as per current language but I am looking at a solution to do this dynamically and bring all fields in one time

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes working on it. Ill update you in some time.

Answer (score 1):

In case of *Static content*  You can use some kind of `translate` pipe or your custom one.

But in case of dynamic binding like you did in your example, Either you can use some global methods to check condition for your selected language like this -

```
<label *ngFor='let item of items'>{{parseLanguage(item)}}</label>

parseLanguage(item) {
  if(this.selectedLang == 'X'){ return item.name_ar}
  else return item.name_en
}
```

Or another way is to get an only single response from the server as per the language selected.

## Update

I have created one pipe for the same which accept whole object containing values of diff. languages and return as per language selected, Hope this works for you -

```
import { Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'translate'})

export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform  {
  languageSelected: string;

  constructor() { }

  transform(value) {
    console.log(value, 'in pipe'); 
    // Made a check for global language selected and return accordingly

    if(this.languageSelected == 'arabic'){
      return value.name_ar;
    }
    else {
      return value.name_en;
    }
  }
}


<p *ngFor='let item of items'>
  {{item | translate}}
</p>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mowwdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: For static content, I use ngx-translate. About using the function, will it not be too bad for performance?. Plus, i need to handle this in every component

Comment: Yes agree, It's not too good but I guess this is the only option in case of dynamic content

Comment: Can we use some kind of pipe ?

Comment: yes we can , but not sure how it will work in case of dynamic content

Comment: my model structure will always be same, name_en and name_ar and so on. also, `en`, `ar` etc can be globally available. So they can be accessed in pipe as well. Can you think of some way ?

Comment: may be, I'll try, when you get an anwer let me know else I'll update my answer

Comment: yup i will, let me know if you try out something

Comment: @ashfaq.p Can you please check my updated answer and let me know if this suits to your use case

Comment: SInce the input will not change even on language change, will the pure pipe work ?

Comment: I think you need to listen to the change in selectedLanguage in the pipe file so that it will reflect relevant changes.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should save your label name in data base and server side and when you send request for give retrieve the field data, label names is coming in json and run *ngfor on this.

json in server side :

```
form1 = { ar : [
  {
    name: 'راقب'
  },
  {
    name: 'ألعاب الأطفال'
  }
], en : [
  {
    name: 'Watches'
  },
  {
    name: 'Toys'
  }
], ... another lang]
```

form2 = {}  and another form

var listOfLabel = fom1['langComingFromClintSide'];
response.send(listOfLabel);

and you code change :

```
<label *ngFor='let item of items'>{{item.name}}</label>
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that I can always get one field from server but I want to handle this case on frontend